# Which database table that holds page items' session state?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I am using Apex 18.2. Could you guide me to the database table that holds page items' session state? And in which schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the one:

```
APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_DATA
```

The following two column are involved but can not remember which one is for which data.

```
ITEM_VALUE_VC2, ITEM_VALUE_CLOB
```

Comment: Generally, I love to get a grasp on what's happening around me. And I wanted to see that a value of a password type field is actually stored encrypted. And in order that when someone knows about data that he should not have I'd know where to look how he got those data. BTW, After googling I find a blog post of you talking about this table and others. Thanks for that.

Comment: Providing such context when originally asking a question can be beneficial in getting a more accurate answer more promptly.

Comment: Pardon me, next time I will provide as much information as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This information is stored within the APEX schemas, and no dictionary view is made available.

Session state is accessed directly for the relevant item, with syntax depending on context. Usually as a bind variable

`:P1_ITEM`

Depending on your intention, it can be possible to dynamically get/set values in bulk.

Comment: The App builder help system for "Store value encrypted in session state" attribute says,
_**"Specify whether to encrypt this item when stored in session state. If the contents of an item contain sensitive data, then you should encrypt the value when it is stored in the Application Express session state management tables. Otherwise, anyone with rights to read the Application Express meta data tables could  potentially write a query to extract this sensitive data."_** I want to know which tables they shouldn't have right to query. @Scott

Comment: Query access to core tables in the APEX% schemas needs to be explicitly granted for this to be a concern. Developers may be a different, far deeper story.

Comment: What is it you want to do ? It could be you're asking the wrong question...